# Running one wheel with clincher and one with Tubular

Tags: tire, wheels

I have a carbon clincher wheelset and am looking to get a disc wheel, but don't want to spend the money for the clincher version. Would there be any foreseeable issue with running one wheel with a clincher tire and the rear with a tubular?

Should I get the same tire in Clincher and Tubular when purchasing tires if this is safe to do?

Comment: If I understand you right, one of the concerns is "can I run different tires on a bike?" and the answer is YES, the tires are totally independent from one another and this can even be used to "tune" the behaviour of the bike, either on an off road, according to personal preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If flat takes you out of the race, then there is no big reason not to do this. As noted, the biggest reason not to is having to carry more flat protection.

You might even decide to purposefully choose different tires - a bit heavier in the rear for a bit of puncture protection, something that adapts to wet a bit better in the front for steering when it starts to drizzle, etc.

Bottom line, not a safety concern.

Happy Riding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't run mixed because it doubles the gear you need to carry, spare tubes for the clincher and a spare tire for the tubular, maybe some extra sealant and hope it sticks depending on the leak.

There is not a need to get the same brand/make/tread tire as the clincher tire won't work on the tubular rim and the tubular tire wont work on the clincher rim, no mix and match so no need to get the same.

You might look at a disc cover for your carbon clinchers. I purchased a [Wheelbuilder AeroJacket disc cover](http://www.wheelbuilder.com/aero-disc-covers.html) and while it does not give the same sound as full disc wheel, it does give just as much aero advantage.

Comment: By same tire I meant the same tire in Clincher and Tubular format, not a clincher for both. Carrying the gear isn't really an issue because if I get a flat I'm out of the race. I was wondering mostly about the safety of riding a clincher front and tubular rear.

Comment: I figured you meant same brand/make of tire, not running clincher on a tubular rim, that wouldn't work. What I meant to convey was that matching the brand/make doesn't matter.